# Updating R-Square when new data becomes available

Tags: regression, r-squared, model-evaluation

Is there a way to update R^2 online?

1- I have a dataset A, and I train a model and measure R^2
2- Now I no longer have access to A but only the R^2 metric
3- Dataset B becomes available, and I want to update the R^2 measurement based on all data points up to here.

Would step 3 be possible without having to access the original dataset? Is there a straightforward mathematical equation for it?

Comment: There is, but you need to retain more than just $R^2$ to do it: you need the means and the full covariance matrix of regressors and response variables: in other words, all first and second multivariate moments.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=online+regression.